# How to take pictures using only the front camera in jetpack compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-camerax

I am trying to take pictures from front camera using jetpack compose. I tried it using `LocalContext.current.getCameraProvider()` but it opens only the back camera. I do not want to open the back camera. I tried [this](https://medium.com/@dpisoni/building-a-simple-photo-app-with-jetpack-compose-camerax-and-coroutines-part-2-camera-preview-cf1d795129f6) to open the camera but I am unable to open the front camera.

I am new to jetpack compose, someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the way:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CameraView(onImageCaptured: (Uri, Boolean) -> Unit, onError: (ImageCaptureException) -> Unit) {

    val context = LocalContext.current
    var lensFacing by remember { mutableStateOf(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK) }
    val imageCapture: ImageCapture = remember {
        ImageCapture.Builder().build()
    }
    val galleryLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
        ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()
    ) { uri: Uri? ->
        if (uri != null) onImageCaptured(uri, true)
    }

    CameraPreviewView(
        imageCapture,
        lensFacing
    ) { cameraUIAction ->
        when (cameraUIAction) {
            is CameraUIAction.OnCameraClick -> {
                imageCapture.takePicture(context, lensFacing, onImageCaptured, onError)
            }
            is CameraUIAction.OnSwitchCameraClick -> {
                lensFacing =
                    if (lensFacing == CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK) CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_FRONT
                    else
                        CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK
            }
            is CameraUIAction.OnGalleryViewClick -> {
                if (true == context.getOutputDirectory().listFiles()?.isNotEmpty()) {
                    galleryLauncher.launch("image/*")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting Unresolved reference error for CameraPreviewView and CameraUIAction